# Error loading TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am trying to add Tika's language detection feature to Solr (6.5.0).
I added the following line to the solrconfig.xml file:

```
<lib dir="C:\Program Files\SOLR\server\tikaLib\" regex="tika-app-1.14.jar" />
```

And langid configuration in solrconfig.xml:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid"> 
    <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
        <str name="langid.fl">text,title,subject,description</str> 
        <str name="langid.langField">language_s</str> 
        <str name="langid.fallback">en</str> 
    </processor> 
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

However I got the error below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:540)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add all jars Tika depends on, those are in

```
contrib\extraction\lib\
```

just add a similar line to solrconfig.xml to the one you added above:

```
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

should do it.

Comment: Actually it worked when I added <lib dir="../tikaLib/" regex="apache-solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />, apparently tika-app-1.14.jar already contains all Tika dependencies.